# Javascript - remove ( ) from a string

Tags: javascript

I have a  string like

```
var test = (-90.298205)
```

i want to remove `( )` character from this string using java script

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: That's not a string, it's a number. A string has to be in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use .

```
var t = '(-90.298205)'; var output = t.replace(/[^\w\s\-\.]/gi, ''); alert(output);`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the string `replace` function with `regular expression`

```
var test = "(-90.298205)";
test = test.replace(/[()]/g, "");
```

Comment: Why is everyone promoting regular expressions like madness?

Answer (score 3):

If the parentheses are always the first and last character, then you don't need a regular expression:

```
test = test.substring(1, test.length - 1);
```

Although it looks like you don't have a string. The expression `(-90.298205)` is simply a (parenthesized) number. Why it's parenthesized is a mystery -- but you can't really "remove" the parentheses around it unless you remove those in the source itself. Even that won't change anything semantically (once parsed/interpreted, there's no difference between the parenthesized and non-parenthesized literal.)

Answer (score -1):

use substring 
for example:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(0, 10);
```

The result of res will be:

```
Hello world
```

Comment: What does substring have to to with removing parentheses?

Comment: No the result will be `Hello worl`

Comment: This is not a very dynamic solution and the substring will also start at " which results in sth like "Hello wor